# How to add single quotes in individual items in a list of list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with 2 columns. I want to group the URL with the help of IP column and get a list of list containing the grouped items.

```
d3 = df2.groupby('IP')['URL'].apply(lambda x:','.join(x.dropna().unique())).reset_index()

dataset =[]
for index, rows in d3.iterrows():
     my_list =[rows.URL]
     dataset.append(my_list)
```

This gives me a list of list which looks like

`[['item1, item2, item3'],['item4'],['item5,item6']]` and so on.

I would like to have it like this:

`[['item1','item2','item3'],['item4'],['item5','item6']]`

How can I achieve this??

Comment: All you would need to do is use `split(',')`  on rows.URL.

`my_list =[rows.URL.split(',')]`

Comment: Hi thanks for replying! `d3.URL.str.split(',')` just returns the same row but within [] . Any idea why items are not within single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()`, like this:

```py
d3 = df2.groupby('IP')['URL'].apply(lambda x:','.join(x.dropna().unique())).reset_index()

dataset =[]
for index, rows in d3.iterrows():
     my_list =[rows.URL]
     grouped_items = [i.strip() for i in my_list[0].split(',')]
     dataset.append(grouped_items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your sub-lists only contain 1 element, you can change `my_list = [rows.URL]` to

```py
my_list = rows.URL.split(',')
```

If they have space or other unwanted characters, try using Regular Expression:

```py
my_list = re.split('\W+', rows.URL)
```

Both ways return a list, you can later extend your `dataset` with it (not append it)

```py
dataset.extend(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the multiple items with individual strings, you should amend your first line of code to aggregate the multiple items into a **list of strings** instead of **joining the items into a single string**.

You got multiple items concatenated into a single string e.g. `'item1, item2, item3'` (with only one and only one pair of single quotes at both ends but not around each item) instead of distinct strings e.g. `'item1'`,`'item2'`,`'item3'` because you joined the individual strings into one string for each group of `IP` by using `','.join(....)` within the `.apply()` function.

Amend your first line of code as follows:

```
d3 = df2.groupby('IP')['URL'].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().unique().tolist()).reset_index()
```

You can also simplify your codes of extracting the list of string with looping by replacing the loop with as simple as one line, as follows:

```
dataset = d3['URL'].tolist()
```

### Demo

**Input data:**

```
import numpy as np

data = {'IP': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
 'URL': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item3', 'item4', np.nan, 'item4', 'item5', 'item5', np.nan, 'item6']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

    IP    URL
0    1  item1
1    1  item2
2    1  item3
3    1  item3
4    2  item4
5    2    NaN
6    2  item4
7    3  item5
8    3  item5
9    3    NaN
10   3  item6
```

**Output**

```
print(dataset)

[['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], ['item4'], ['item5', 'item6']]
```